# Error: error on "int"

Tags: processing

I'm new to Processing and I need to create a random color, but it returns an error.

```java
int R = (int)(Math.random()*255);
int G = (int)(Math.random()*255);
int B = (int)(Math.random()*255);
color randomColor = new color(R,G,B);
```

The final line in this returns error on "int" 
Did I not write the last line properly?

Comment: Can you share the exact text of the error?

Comment: Does color not have a capital C

Comment: Are you sure of `color`?

Comment: Commenters: Please note that this is a [tag:processing] question, and [Processing != Java](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java). Specifically, lower-case `color` is indeed a type in Processing.

Comment: @KevinWorkman as a note, I was genuinely asking ^^ I don't know java but seemed a suitable guess

Comment: @WhyIsCode, can you please explain in more detail, are you asking about [processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_(programming_language)) the language? Or Java itself? You mention `java` in your text body, but also have processing tagged, These are different languages.

Comment: @MattClark They aren't really separate languages. Processing is built on top of Java.

Comment: Sure, it is built on top of java, but syntax is different. Java answers will not always work in Processing, and Processing answers will not always work in Java. The question needs to be more clear, if the author actually intended to tag processing as the language.

Comment: OP has edited the question to clarify that he IS indeed talking about processing, and not Java specifically. Will delete my now irrelevant answer.

Comment: @MattClark That's not quite true. Java answers will often work in Processing, and Processing answers will often work in Java. Processing is a Java library. It just so happens that this question was asking about a pseudo-type specific to Processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers don't realize that `color` is a type in Processing.

Your problem is that you're trying to use a `new color()` constructor, which doesn't exist. Try using the `color()` function, like this:

```java
color randomColor = color(R,G,B);
```

More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/color_.html).

Also note that Processing has its own `random()` function that you should be using instead of directly calling `Math.random()` yourself.

**Edit:** Turns out other people have been confused by this, and [here](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/3851) is a discussion on implementing better error messages.

Comment: Ah, I suppose looking for Java isn't always correct when using Processing.